# Read JournalEntry Lines and Details

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

In the QuickBooks PHP API V3 currently, I get the JournalEntries. But I cannot get the Line and Line details - how do I do this?

```
$journalEntrys = $JournalEntryService->query($Context, $realm, "select * from JournalEntry WHERE TxnDate >= '" .$startDate ."' AND TxnDate <= '" .$endDate ."'");

//print_r($customers);

foreach ($journalEntrys as $JournalEntry)
{
    //NEED TO GET EACH LIKE AND EACH LINE DETAIL...HOW?
    $line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
    $line = $JournalEntry->getLine();
    array_push($returnArray, array("id"=>str_replace("}", "", str_replace("{-", "", $JournalEntry->getId())),"txnDate"=>$JournalEntry->getTxnDate(),"lines"=>$line->getId(),"TotalAmt"=>$JournalEntry->getTotalAmt()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a "for" loop to look through the lines...

```
$num_lines = $JournalEntry->countLine();   // How many lines are there? 

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_lines; $i++)
{
  $Line = $JournalEntry->getLine($i);   // Get a line
  print_r($Line);   // Print out the line object

  $details = $Line->getJournalEntryLineDetail();   // Get the details
  print_r($details);   // Print out the details
}
```